# Safari browser text bleeding out of div

Tags: html, css, safari, macos-sierra

I have a strange issue that only occurs in Safari. All other browsers are okay. I am on MacOS Sierra and now upgraded to High Sierra - both has exact same behaviour.

- text inside `<p>` is bleeding out of the parent container which is a `<div>`
- text flows onto images that are set with float / right align properties.
- not all `<p>` tags are affected and all `<p>` tags inside collapsed containers are looking fine when expanded.
- tried overflow-wrap and word-break properties

This was not an issue prior to some browser upgrade while on Sierra. Site that has this issue: https://www.worldsbestoil.ca This issues can be found throughout the site, like this page: https://www.worldsbestoil.ca/pc-program.php scroll down to see issues.

I would like to know what is causing this weird problem. Is it some css properties elsewhere or is it due to lack of some properties?

[image: Screenshot 1:]

[image: Screenshot 2:]

Comment: I suggest you provide some screenshots so others can help you out.

Comment: I just tested it, and I am not seeing any issues.

Comment: did you test from Mac/Safari?

Comment: Yeah, on Sierra. It looks fine on my end. Not sure what is going on. Seems like it must just be a bug with Safari.

Comment: added some screenshot from the 2 page links provided above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, quite strange, especially because this issue does not occur consistently. While I cannot give you a definite answer why exactly this happens (no time to do a thorough analysis) at least a

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on that p tags seems to help, and if only for a quick fix.

Comment: yes, it seems to work. Can I add this to global rules for `<p>`tags or would it have other unexpected results?

Comment: These three settings seems to work `overflow: hidden, scroll & auto`. I think I should go ahead and add `overflow: auto`? What do you think?

Comment: Issue resolved with a global css rule `p{overflow:auto}`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! But actually, still I wonder why this happens. Maybe a Safari bug?

Comment: And yeah `overflow: auto` is even better if that works.

Comment: yeah, looks like a Safari bug